# What's the function of であられる?

Tags: passive-voice, honorifics, copula

I came across another confusing Japanese translation of the Qur'an. Here's the Arabic text:

> قُلۡ هُوَ اللّٰهُ اَحَدٌ​ (the Qur'an chapter 112 verse 1)

Here's the English translation:

> Say, He is Allāh, [who is] One.

Now, I found 2 different translations of that sentence. The first one:

> 言え，かれはアッラー，唯一なる御方であられる。(Ryoichi Mita)

The second one:

> 言え。かれはアッラー、唯一なるお方。(Saeed Sato)

What is the function of であられる in the first Japanese translation?

I already tried searching for the answer in this website, but I can't seem to find one. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is copula *de ar-* ("to be") with suffix *-are-*.

In the context of referring to deities, most likely honorific/respectual function of this suffix is intended.

You most likely heard [suffix *-are-*](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B) described as suffix of passive voice, but this suffix actually has 4 functions (and other functions in dialects) (using order of meanings from that dictionary):

1. spontaneous action
2. passive voice
3. potential
4. honorific/respectual

> 4. （尊敬）動作の主語に対する軽い敬意の念を表す。

> 4. (Respect) Expresses light sense of respect towards subject of action.